# String still optional in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to assign a string to a label like so:

```
self.MsgBlock4.text = "\(wsQAshowTagArray![0]["MsgBlock4"]!)"
```

But it display the label like so `Optional(James)` how do I remove the Optional() ?

The Dictionary inside the array comes from here:

```
self.wsQAshowTag(Int(barcode)!, completion: { wsQAshowTagArray in

})
```

Here is the method:

```
func wsQAshowTag(tag: Int, completion: ([AnyObject]? -> Void)) {
        let requestString = NSString(format: "URL?wsQATag=%d", tag) as String
        let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: requestString)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [AnyObject]
                completion(result)
            }
            catch {
                completion(nil)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: what is type of `wsQAshowTagArray`? You should just unwrap the result one more time.

Comment: Try changing this `completion(result)` to `completion(result!)`. Or change `completion: ([AnyObject]? -> Void))` to `completion: ([AnyObject]! -> Void))`

Comment: Don't make your array an optional.

Comment: @totoajax this did not work...Optional() is still appearing, I tried both your solutions.

Comment: Don't use string interpolation – just assign the string directly, and the problem will present itself. You also [shouldn't be force unwrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are optionals and the type can be `AnyObject`, optional chaining / downcasting and providing a default value using the nil coalescing operator seem the safest approach. If you're expecting the item to be a `String`:

```
self.MsgBlock4.text = (wsQAshowTagArray?[0]["MsgBlock4"] as? String) ?? ""
```

Or I guess for any type that conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` you can use its `description`

```
self.MsgBlock4.text = (wsQAshowTagArray?[0]["MsgBlock4"] as? CustomStringConvertible)?.description ?? ""
```